# C++ Win32 Gdiplus program crash trying to delete Gdiplus::Bitmap

Tags: c++, gdi+

Basically, I am trying to find out if a Gdiplus::Bitmap* is not NULL (or 0). If so delete it, and then create a "new Gdiplus::Bitmap()" in place. I am trying to do this to prevent any future memory leak.

I've tried quite a few things, if I create the bitmap and then call delete, it works fine (minus the null check.)

```
// private
Gdiplus::Bitmap* last_frame_bmp;

// public
foo::foo() {
    if (last_frame_bmp != NULL) { delete last_frame_bmp; }
    last_frame_bmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat32bppPARGB);
}
```

By crash, I mean, the program hangs and doesn't start.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why `Gdiplus::last_frame_bmp` rather than just `last_frame_bmp`?

Comment: @AlanStokes err, made some mistakes copy and pasting, the code is now how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set `Gdiplus::last_frame_bmp = NULL` in the constructor of the class. It now works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your test is the wrong way round - you're only deleting if it's null. In any case it is entirely safe to `delete` a null pointer; it has no effect, so you'd be much better off without the condition at all.

But no good C++ code ever does an explicit `delete` anyway; we have smart pointers to do that for us.

Your crash is because you corrupted memory somewhere else - too much explicit `new` and `delete` I would think.

Comment: that was my mistake, I was testing, it was originally  !=. That part, creating the bitmap, is actually run only once. But I just wanted to add the check for the heck of it. Now it bothers me that that is stopping the program. I also fixed the other issue.

Comment: You still don't need to check for null at all before cashing `de!ete`. And good C++ code almost never uses `delete` - or indeed `new`.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Are you sure `last_frame_bmp` has been initialised before you try to delete it? Your code doesn't show it being set to anything, so it could well have a random value (not pointing at a valid object) and then you try to delete that. You should declare at the point where you need to use a variable; then you won't have this issue.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou it had not been initialized, I was hoping this could check with a comparison to NULL, and create it if not. Now thinking, that shouldn't/ would not work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using non-initialized variable.

Change it to

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* last_frame_bmp = nullptr;
```

and it will work.

BTW: Do you call [GdiplusStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to initialize GDI+ ? You have to.

Comment: It's explicitly stated to be global and hence is zero initialised. In any case there is unspecified code between declaration and `delete`.

Comment: @AlanStokes  C++ has no explicit  "global" declaration. There is static storage class but that one is not static.

Comment: @c-smile alright, I updated the code to be more in context. The problem would come from not being initialized. Because of its location, I can't init it there. It does work if I initialize it before.

Comment: It's called namespace scope. Although it turns out the OP was inaccurate anyway.